# javascript: is there any advantage or difference in specifying properties names as text when using literal objects?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

all right, it's far easier showing some code...

Is there any performance or any other kind of difference between this javascript code

```
var obj = {
  'id':   0,
  'name': 'new obj'
};
```

and

```
var obj = {
  id:   0,
  name: 'new obj'
};
```

(Have a look at the single quotes surrounding id and name)

--

If I recall correctly, in php it was adviced to always use the single quotes, because if not the interpreter had to check if there existed a variable with that name...

Comment: But for disambiguate certain cases, I'd say it should not make any difference for the interpretor.

Comment: if PHP needs to check to see if a variable with that name already existed, it's because PHP interprets the variables... JS, for keys, does not. What I mean by that is illustrated here:

    var name = 'carpeliam';
    var nameObj = {name: name}; // same as {'name': name}

With JS, when you create objects in this way, keys will never be evaluated. Sidenote, if you ever needed this, you'd have to do this:

    var key = 'carpeliam';
    var nameObj = {}; nameObj[key] = 'Some value';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no performance difference i believe.

Usually we use quotes to use reserved words in JavaScript like `class`, which is not allowed to be used as an object key.

Answer (score 2):

If your object has names that are not legal identifiers (have spaces or punctuation,  start with numbers), or are reserved or keywords, or are the same as any variable in scope, they have to be quoted. Otherwise it doesn't matter, javascript uses the names you give it.

Answer (score 1):

As kennebec points out, some characters are not allowed in unquoted keys.

The main point however (in my opinion) is that the difference is so small that optimalisation on these kind of things is not really worth it. Find other bottlenecks (loops and AJAX calls most often) and fix those first, before going to do micro optimalisation.